# Observable on angular firestore document not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to assign an observable of a firestore document to  an attribute of a service.  I want to use it later with async pipe in template

I tried in all ways but can't get it work. Some help would be really great.

```
export class UserService {
    private currentUserObservable: Observable<User>;

    loadUserObservable(uid){ 
    this.currentUserObservable =this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges()
    }
}

<div *ngIf="userService.currentUserObservable | async as user">
Displayname: {{ user.displayName }}
</div>
```

Comment: I think valueChanges should already return an observable. Can you create a repro? stackblitz is a great way to share code in here.

Comment: sorry there was a piece missing in the code (is my first time here)...

Comment: Create a Service and get the data there, (here is how to do a service https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-4), return to the data component and make a subscribe, after that it will have the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here you have an example of login library with sync user in database you can study it if you want to.

**Auth module:**
https://bitbucket.org/mises543/fire-ngx-auth/src/master/projects/auth/src/lib/

**example app using this module:**
https://bitbucket.org/mises543/fire-ngx-auth/src/master/projects/auth-test/

**npm:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fire-ngx/auth

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. The problem was indeed the observable got lost - which is resolve in you code by:       this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          if (user) {
            if (this.config.enableFirestoreSync) {
              this.syncService.updateUserData(user)
              return this.syncService.getUserData(user.uid)
            } else {
              return of(user)
            }
          } else {
            return of(null)
          }
        })

Comment: No problem i'll try to post this lib on NPM in a future.